# Method inside method of class in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new in python and I got stuck to get data inside method.

```
class ho:
    def hi(self):
        print('hi')
        def hello(self,):
            print('hello')

h = ho()
print(h.hi())
```

I got the value of method **hi()** but can't print **hello**

Comment: Here's a programming secret that nobody will tell you: if you don't call a function, it doesn't get called.

Comment: It's a *function* in a method (it won't get the `self` parameter), and it's only accessible *within* that method.

Comment: how can i call hello() function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the method `hi()` you are defining a local function `hello`, but not calling it.

Apart from this, your code has some errors:

1. You do not need to pass `self` when defining `hello`
2. You do not need to `print(h.hi())` but only `h.hi()` since it calls `print` internally.

So a working version would be:

```
class ho:
    def hi(self):
        print('hi')
        def hello():
            print('hello')
        hello()

h = ho()

h.hi()
```

**TIP:** Give more explicative names to variables and functions.

Comment: Of course, generally it does not make so much sense to define a function and call it inside a method like this.